# How is serine ionized in serine proteases?

Tags: biochemistry

I read that serine isn't strongly acidic so how is it that in serine proteases it is able to have its pKa lowered by the catalytic triad?

Comment: Could you edit to show a bit more what you already found out. For example, what is the pKa of serine in water, and what is it in the context of a serine protease? Also, how low do you think the pKa has to be in order for it to be a good catalyst?